# PostgreSQL connection string for Microsoft hosted Azure pipelines agent

Tags: postgresql, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, connection-string, npgsql

Per [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software) [docs](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-Readme.md), PostgreSQL server is there and service just needs to be started, no password needed. However, what is the proper connection string for Npgsql? When

```
Host=localhost;Database=postgres;Username=postgres
```

is used, an exception is thrown

```cs
Unhandled exception. Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): No password has been provided but the backend requires one (in SASL/SCRAM-SHA-256)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.AuthenticateSASL(List`1 mechanisms, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Authenticate(String username, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.AllocateLong(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
   at PostgresqlExtensions.PostgresqlDatabase(SupportedDatabasesForEnsureDatabase supported, String connectionString, IUpgradeLog logger, X509Certificate2 certificate)
   at PostgresqlExtensions.PostgresqlDatabase(SupportedDatabasesForEnsureDatabase supported, String connectionString, IUpgradeLog logger)
   at PostgresqlExtensions.PostgresqlDatabase(SupportedDatabasesForEnsureDatabase supported, String connectionString)
```

Comment: The page you linked to doesn't say a password is not needed.  And the error message clearly says one is needed.  (And it isn't even clear that those are the right docs.  Are Github Actions and Azure Pipelines the same thing?)

Comment: Added more links to docs